# Unable to import to hbase from mysql via oozie

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, sqoop, oozie

I have been trying to import data from a mysql table to hbase using oozie via sqoop

My sqoop import command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://some_ip/myDatabase 
--username User --password-file /etc/User.password 
--hbase-create-table --table mytbl 
--columns &quot;column1,column2,column3,column4&quot; 
--hbase-table mynamespace:mytbl --column-family default
--hbase-row-key column1 -m 1 --incremental lastmodified 
--check-column column4
```

This, when run via command-line, works like a charm. However, when I try to run this from an oozie workflow as below:

```
<action name="mytbl">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql://some_ip/myDatabase 
        --username User --password-file /etc/User.password 
        --hbase-create-table --table mytbl 
        --columns &quot;column1,column2,column3,column4&quot; 
        --hbase-table mynamespace:mytbl --column-family default 
        --hbase-row-key column1 -m 1 --incremental lastmodified 
        --check-column column4
        </command>
        <file>/oozie-lib/hbase-client-1.1.3.jar#hbase-client-1.1.3.jar</file>
        <file>/oozie-lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.3.jar#hbase-protocol-1.1.3.jar</file>
        <file>/oozie-lib/hbase-server-1.1.3.jar#hbase-server-1.1.3.jar</file>
        <file>/oozie-lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.1.3.jar#hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.1.3.jar</file>
        <file>/oozie-lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.1.3.jar#hbase-hadoop-compat-1.1.3.jar</file>
        <file>/oozie-lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar#mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar</file>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="notify"/>
</action>
```

The jars' links mentioned are well supplemented in hdfs and so is the "error to" action notify.

I have been getting the following exception while executing the oozie workflow.

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can’t get the locations
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:312)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:402)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:217)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:271)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:507)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
```

I have tried changing the user to 'hdfs' executing the oozie job using the '-doas' parameter, yet no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:: I tried adding

```
<job-xml>${hbaseXml}</job-xml>
```

with proper path to hbase-site.xml, But then started getting the following exception..

```
ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Thu May 25 18:10:43 IST 2017, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68220: row 'mynamespace:mytbl,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=myJobTracker,60020,1495464595462, seqNum=0

        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:286)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:867)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:420)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:217)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:271)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:507)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:193)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:176)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:56)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68220: row 'mynamespace:mytbl,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=myJobtracker,60020,1495464595462, seqNum=0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:80)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:381)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:355)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:34094)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:394)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:225)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yammer.metrics.core.Gauge
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 14 more
```

I tried adding metrics-core-3.0.2.jar to the additional jars list. still getting the same exception.

Comment: _"Can’t get the locations"_ >> did you pass a valid `hbase-site.xml` config file to your job? Because a job running inside of a YARN container does not have the same default config as a Sqoop command that you run on the Edge Node...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, tried this, now getting other exception as edited in the question. Thanks a lot anyways.